# Question on negative energy solutions to the photoelectric effect

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, electrons, photoelectric-effect

the photoelectric effect was explained by Einstein as $$\frac12mv^2=\hbar\omega - W$$ where $W$ is the binding energy of the atom that the electron is in, and $\hbar\omega$ is the energy of the photon that strikes said electron. I know that in order for the electron to leave its atom, $\hbar\omega>W$ and if $\hbar\omega=W$ then the kinetic energy is zero and thus there is no motion. But, if $\hbar\omega<W$ we get a negative solution for the kinetic energy. How can sense be made of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\hbar\omega<W$, then no matter how intensely you shine light at the metal, no current will flow.

In other words, no electrons are ejected. This was one of the key experimental observations of the photoelectric effect.

Answer (score 0):

Well, statements on arbitrarily high quantities, in this case intensities, are always difficult. Typically the behaviour of a system is not linear with all its parameters. To be more specific, what is understood under  photoelectric effect is in the limit if low light intensities and low temperature of the metal. At higher intensities multiphoton absorption becomes a possible pass while at finite temperature the electron gas in the metal has some thermal energy. This does not say in any way that the concept of the photoelectric effect is not correct. Energy and momentum are certainly conserved.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/360645)